# how to get sum value of sub-child element in xml file

Tags: php, xml, sum

I need to get the sum total of a sub-child element from mxl file My structure of xml file is as follow

```
<pagevalues>
    <ac>
        <b1>1</b1>
        <b2>2</b2>
        <b3>3</b3>
        <b4>4</b4>
        <b5>5</b5>
        <pc>6</pc>
    </ac>
<pagevalues>
```

I tried following approach but get Total =0

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($target_url);
$total=0;
foreach($xml->ac as $data)
{    
    $total += $data;
}
echo 'Total is: ' . $total;
```

How do you post to sub-child element Here is my form code

This is my form

```
<form action='showXML.php' method='POST'>
car <input type='text' name='car'>
<br />
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

My xml file structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pagevalue>
    <model>
        <car>bmw</car>
    </model>
</pagevalue>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop isn't accessing the last level of data, `$xml->ac` is only taking the `<ac>` element as a whole.  You need to access the child nodes of the `<ac>` element...

```
foreach($xml->ac->children() as $data)
```

Comment: Just a tip - if you are ever unsure about what element you are dealing with, you can just add `echo $data->asXML();` to the code and see what the data actually is as opposed to what you are hoping for.

Comment: On another note how do you post to a sub-child element. Will add code to main question

Comment: If you have a new question, it may be better to post it separately as I have not been on SO as much recently and so may not have time to answer.